# regular-expression to strip Minecraft color codes from string

Tags: php, regex

The Minecraft client colors messages with the following format:
§6Gold text

Where § denotes the start of a color code and the following character ([0-9A-FK-OR]). Is there a way I can use preg_replace to remove all of these from a string?

```
(?i)§[0-9A-FK-OR]
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of the text and desired output, so we can test with them please?

Comment: §6Gold§cRed§oRed italic§rReset to normal§kSwirly letters§rReset§6Gold§lGold bold

Comment: Is that expected input or desired output? Do you want the colours listed in an array? We need more information about what it is you are trying to achieve. Sorry.

Comment: Input. Output would be GoldRedRed italicReset to normalSwirly lettersReset etc etc

Comment: Omega's method is fine though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$s = preg_replace('/\xA7[0-9A-FK-OR]+/i', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work with some words. It strips to much. Try this...

```
$s = preg_replace('/\xA7[0-9A-FK-OR]/i', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

This strips the color codes:

```
$motd = preg_replace('/\xa7./','',$motd);
```

You probably also want to strip the 0xc2 characters:

```
$motd = preg_replace('/\xc2|\xa7./','',$motd)
```

But since servers can send anything, including malicious strings, this would be better:

```
$motd = preg_replace('/\xa7./','',$motd);
$motd = filter_var($motd,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```